# Проблемы с доступом к элементам на странице через скрипт

Tags: javascript, html

Необходимо программно выбрать `option` из `select`. C данной задачей проблем нет, но есть другая проблема. До тех пор пока пользователь не выберет какой-либо `option`, кнопка будет неактивна. При ручном выборе опции все работает нормально, но пытаясь сделать это программным путем, кнопка остается неактивной.

Я попробовал вызывать в ручную событие `onchange` у селекта, но он выдает ошибку:

> Uncaught TypeError: size.onchange is not a function

хотя я через консоль разработчика методом `getEventListeners` проверял, событие навешивается на элемент.

Ниже представлен код:

выбираем значение select и пытаемся вызвать метод `onchange();`

```
var size = document.getElementsByClassName('moostach')[0];
size.selectedIndex = 3;
size.onchange();
```

событие, которое привязано к селекту и вызывается при изменении опции:

```
defn = function(event){
                event = new DOMEvent(event, self.getWindow());
                if (condition.call(self, event) === false) event.stop();
            };
```

Странно то, что событие `onclick` кнопки, которая активируется после выбора опции, содержит этот же самый код.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А код где? Людям гадать, что да как там реализовано?

Comment: Да, прошу прощения, об этом как-то не подумал. 
Сейчас все добавлю

Comment: `хотя я через консоль разработчика проверял, событие навешивается на элемент.` - а как проверяли? туда что-то выводилось или вы вручную в консоль добавляли событие?

Comment: проверял методом getEventListeners

Comment: Возможно, когда вы программно вызываете `size.onchange()`, то события еще нету. Т.е. код, который привязывает событие еще не выполнился. Нужно больше кода!

Comment: Отнюдь, событие к моменту вызова уже привязано к элементу. Добавил скрин к теме

Comment: Tik, что бы Stepan Kasyanenko получил уведомление о твоем комменте, ты должен к нему обратиться... Он не получит уведомление, что ты ответил на его коммент...  Когда начинаешь писать коммент  нажми на собачку "@" потом первую букву имени того к кому хочешь обратиться.  В зависимости от имени, Русские или латинский  буквы в имени...  И еще, если пишешь коммент автору  вопроса или ответа под непосредственно под вопросом или ответом, обращаться не надо, уведомление само придет...

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего ваш DOM еще не готов когда вы вызываете метод `size.onchange()`

```
function ready() {
  // действия с домом size.onchange()
}
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", ready);
```